# Colimit of a (relatively) complicated diagram

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

I want to compute the colimit of the following diagram, where $A$ is some set.

[image]

I was also wondering about how to approach these complicated diagrams in general.

Thanks!

Comment: How can you "represent" the morphisms from such a diagram to an arbitrary set $B$?

Comment: @Mindlack, I'm thinking it may be disjoint union of A four times with whatever is picked out by the map $\{*\} \rightarrow A$ being quotiented together.

Comment: Yes, I think that’s it. A formal proof might be a bit of a pain, though.